# Bash if statement: Can I do an assignment and comparison?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, if-statement

I want to do something like:

```
if [ CURRENT=$(stat -c %Y $STATUS_FILE) -ne $LASTUPDATE ]
    then LASTUPDATE = $CURRENT
fi
```

That is... I want to assign a variable and do a comparison since I'll use that variable later

Comment: Also look at:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62660316/bash-if-statement-comparison-not-working-with-assignment

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Absolutely.

```
$ echo "$foo"

$ echo "${foo=$(echo bar)}"
bar
$ echo "$foo"
bar
```

Comment: I think you completely missed the point of his question. I think he wants to do an assignment inside of an IF statement.

Comment: Thank you, I had been playing with that but omitted the quotes, not realizing my mistake.

Comment: Nope, he got it, I was able to plop this right down in an IF statement successfully, example: if [ "${VAR=$(echo 1)}" -eq 1 ]; echo $VAR; yields "1"

Comment: Okay, my bad then. I'd remove my down vote, but I waited too long... if you edit your answer, I can remove it... :)