# Bash if statement: Comparison not working with assignment

Tags: bash, if-statement

In the following `test_if2()` works as expected but `test_if` not. The difference is that in `test_if()` I do a variable assignment. Where is the error?

```
test_if() {
  declare file_path
  if [[ -n ${file_path=$(echo "")} || -n ${file_path=$(echo "Hi")} ]]; then
    echo Non null: ${file_path}
  else
    echo null
  fi      
}

test_if2() {
  declare file_path
  declare greet="Hello"
  if [[ -n $(echo "") || -n $(echo "Hi") ]]; then
    echo Non null
  else
    echo null
  fi      
}

test_if #prints null
test_if2 #prints Non null
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the first `-n ${file_path=$(echo "")}`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Originally instead of `echo` I would call a function that could return an empty string. I decided to replace it with `echo ""` to make it as close to the original script as possible.

Comment: Ok, I see. It seems Mark's answer should solve the problem or is there still something missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `:=` instead of  `=` for the behavior you are looking for.

`${param=word}` does not make the assignment if param is set but empty (which is what `declare param` does).  Use `${param:=word}` to cover the case of an empty param as well.

Your issue is that the assignment is not being performed and the returned value is empty.

I tested your expression on MacOS as follows:

```
file_path=Bye
echo ${file_path=$(echo "Hi")}  # returns Bye 
echo $file_path                 # returns Bye
```

And alternatively:

```
unset file_path
echo ${file_path=$(echo "Hi")}  # returns Hi 
echo $file_path                 # returns Hi
```

Lastly let's see if there is a different behavior when consider unset and empty:

```
file_path=""
echo ${file_path=$(echo "Hi")}  # returns nothing 
echo $file_path                 # returns nothing
```

And we may as well repeat your code exactly:

```
declare file_path
echo ${file_path=$(echo "Hi")}  # returns Nothing
echo $file_path                 # returns Nothing
```

So, if we review your code, we can see why test_if() return "null".

Thus, I'm going to conclude that ${param=word} makes the assignment only if param is unset.  Consider this code instead:

```
test_if() {
  declare file_path
  if [[ -n ${file_path:=$(echo "")} || -n ${file_path:=$(echo "Hi")} ]]; then
    echo Non null: ${file_path}
  else
    echo null
  fi      
}

echo "test_if() returns $(test_if)" # test_if() returns Non null: Hi
```

The use of `:=` assigns a value if the param is empty or unset.  So, this will make your code work , since you declare file_path but didn't assign a value initially, leaving it empty (but set).

Comment: I reviewed the behavior again on my MAC and got different results.  The ${param=word} is returning word unconditionally, without assignment to param.  I've updated my post.  Anyway, my point was , try using := instead.  Be aware that this will only assign a value if one is not already in the variable.  And since you are declaring file_path without assignig it, I think ${:=} is the construct you want.  It fixes the code.

Comment: Good. Also, since I use this construct inside a loop I have to either unset the variable or assign null to it before the `if`

Answer (score 1):

```
file_path="foo"

if [[ -n ${file_path=bar} ]]; then
    echo "got>$file_path<"
else
    echo "no file_path"
fi
```

The assignment of `file_path` inside the parameter expansion has no effect if `file_path` has already been set and the program will therefore print

```
got>foo<
```

The same happens in your condition.

The first condition sets `file_path=""` and since the `-n` test fails for blank strings, it tries the second condition.

The second will however *not* set `file_path="HI"` because it's already set to `""` - and the second `-n` test therefore also fails.

Comment: The correct way is to use `:=` and set the variable to `null` before the `if`. Relevant link:
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

Comment: @Roland - I'm glad you agree with me - `:=` is what you want.

Comment: @Roland [`${parameter=word}`](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#assign_a_default_value) sets if the variable is unset. I tried answering why you had a problem.